# escaping metachar in javascripot regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a fragment of a string that I am looking for that begins and ends with the DOT . char.

I am trying to parse this in javascript with:

```
var regex = new RegExp('\\.([^\\.]+)\\.', '');
var ar = s.match(regex);
```

But it doesn't work.  What am I doing wrong?  By the way, there is more to the regex, but I think this is the part that is not working, as the other parts are so simple.

Comment: new RegExp("\.(.*?)\.", "g") maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can strip one level of escaping by using the regular expression literal syntax:

```
var regex = /\.([^.]+)\./;
```

Additionally to that, inside `[…]` the `.` does not have the special meaning as outside.